# Windows 8 - Storing generic lists in Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, settings

Is there a trick to storing a List in Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values array?  I've tried adding one and it says the data type is not supported.

> WinRT information: Error trying to serialize the value to be written
>   to the application data store
>
> Additional information: Data of this type is not supported.

This code worked fine as is when I was using the Silverlight local settings storage.  Do I need to help the api serialize my  object?  The object in the list just has a few public properties consisting of simple Integers and Strings.

I'm trying to store a

```
List<Animal>
```

where

```
public class Animal
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to store (Type of the `List`)?

Comment: Updated the question to show the classes involved.

Comment: can you post the serialization code too.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [StorageHelper](http://codepaste.net/gtu5mq) to store data, it makes it really easy, give it a spin.

Thanks to [@JerryNixon](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and ended up saving and restoring an array, converting my List to and from the array.

So, in your case, use List (because it's easier) throughout the app but save and restore Animal[] to LocalSettings.

Another gotcha to be aware of is that your array cannot be null or empty, so have a dummy Animal for that case and recognize it in your save and restore code.